# Debian Jessie xfce4: Customize Theme

Tags: debian, xfce4

How can I set the border width and increase the system fonts?
I can only set font size for application menu and window title in

Settings -> Appearance
and
Settings -> Window Manager

but not for menu in application, as you can see in the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

and I would also like to increase the border width.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the systemwide fontsize you can try to raise the DPI. The Setting should be at the same place where the font hinting is too. (Sorry, I'm not sitting in front of my Linux PC with xfce at the moment).

Comment: thanks. i know that and i have adjust my fontsize. to you know how to change the border width?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by border width. Do you mean the blue line in your screenshot? The text width line?

Comment: the window title line

Comment: I don't know if this is possible. You could try to use some other themes, which might use bigger titlebars.